# Normalisation of (2D) homogeneous coordinates

Tags: computer-vision

I've been doing some operations with 2D points expressed in homogeneous coordinates (x, y, w). Sometimes one of the coordinates becomes very large, and this can easily affect subsequent results.

For example, determining intersections can be calculated easily with a vector x-product. This can produce large numbers. Eg. (50, 100, 1) x (-100, 50, 1) = (50, -150, 12500)

I feel these results should be somehow normalised. In the example above, simply by dividing all coordinates by 12500 seems sensible. In general I can see 2 ways:

1. divide by the coordinate with the largest absolute value (may not be w), or
2. divide by w (if w != 0) so that every point is expressed as either (x, y, 0) or (x, y, 1).

So my question is, which way is better and why?

I'm using c# with `float` values, if that's of any practical relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downscaling by the max absolute value of the components is the safer option among all correct ones - you never have to worry about overflows as long as the max > 1.0. Dividing by w is only required to convert to Euclidean points.

Incidentally, working with floats is rarely a good idea in internal calculations, although it may make sense for storing final results that correspond to physical quantities you measure. When doing geometrical calculations, in my experience, truncation errors often propagate fast enough, even with well conditioned algorithms, to make calculated results in single precision rather worthless.